# Django asynchronous call

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

I'm wondering if there is a way to make a request to my Django backend that runs asynchronous.  At page load, I need to kick off a process that takes ~30 seconds, but while it is running I cannot perform any other actions on the page that require a response from Django (specifically waiting on data for jqGrids).

Is there an easy way to tell Django that certain methods should be run asynchronously?

Answer (score 2):

Django has not a native way to do asynchronous tasks but you could see Celery and using a django-celery task.

Celery web: http://www.celeryproject.org/
Django-Celery web: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery

Comment: Could you approve the solution if it was useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use celery. Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing. You can read more about celery [here](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

[This](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/) is a great tutorial for setting up celery.